# How to integrate CKFinder with CKEditor in xcrud Data management system?

Tags: php, ckfinder

I'm using `xcrud` library data management system and I could load `ckeditor` by this code:

```
Xcrud_config::$editor_url = dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]).'/../ckeditor/ckeditor.js';
```

Now, how can I load `ckfinder` for `ckeditor` in `xcrud`?

Answer (score 0):

The integration between CKEditor and CKFinder should be done in JavaScript. Unfortunately, I don't know Xcrud, so I can't tell you what is the best way to provide custom JavaScript to be executed on a page. I think the most suitable way may be the *Manual Integration*, as this can be done in CKEditor configuration.

Please have a look at following CKFinder documentation page for more details about integration with CKEditor:
http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/guide/dev_ckeditor